# Example for Drupal plugin

Tags: drupal, mediaelement.js

I installed the module and the libraries API and the mediaelement package here. I created the filefield and selected `medieelement_audio`.

I just dont know what to type when I add a new content. Could you give me an example?

I tried `<audio>` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [MediaElement](http://drupal.org/project/mediaelement) Drupal module? If so, then you'll want to add a "MediaElement Audio" file field to your content in the content type settings. Once you do that, the field should show up when you visit node/add/mycontenttype .